# ajax success not successful

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm not sure what's happening here, but I'm not able to get a successful response. Here is my code:

```
function sendCallAjaxUsingJson(theUrl, theData, successCallbackFunction, timeoutCallbackFunction, otherErrorCallback, timeoutValueMilli)
{
    var successFn = successCallbackFunction; 
    var timeoutFn = timeoutCallbackFunction; 
    var otherFn = otherErrorCallback;
    if(!(typeof successFn === 'function') || !(typeof timeoutFn === 'function') || !(typeof otherFn === 'function')) 
        return false;

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: theUrl,
        timeout:timeoutValueMilli,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { json: JSON.stringify(theData) },
        success:successFn,
        error: function(x, t, m) {
                   if(t==="timeout") {
                        timeoutFn();
                    } else {
                        otherFn();
                    }
                }
    });
}
```

On the server side I'm using PHP.

I can trigger the timeout function by making the PHP script `sleep` for 2 sec and using a 1000 millisec timeout. The Timeout function executes correctly. However, when I just echo a string from the script, I don't get the success function to fire. Instead, the `otherFn` fires from above. Using Firebug, I can see that the string I echo'ed from the script was successfully received.

So why is it calling the error script? It appears that everything is successful, but it fires the error function.

Comment: Please remember, if data expected was json, and the incoming data is not json, the request will fail though it received the output from the server.

Comment: @itachi This is likely the issue. I didn't find reference to this in the jQuery API: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ but I'm glad you pointed it out.

Comment: if `otherFn` is executing, what is the value of `t` are you getting. It may give some clue.

Comment: Try outputting a valid json data from server and it should trigger the success function. Again note, `success` and `error` are deprecated. Use `done` and `fail`.

Comment: where is the response status, it should be 200. But it might be a parse error - check your browser console to configm

Comment: If you're just echoing a string, change the output to simply "html"... add it between the last '})', like this },'html');